# SharePoint 2013 Workflows List does not exist error- Lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Get error when refer to lookup column in SPD 2013
SharePoint 2013 Workflows List does not exist error.RequestorId: 29235e5e-b907-f47c-0000-000000000000. Details: RequestorId: 29235e5e-b907-f47c-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"error":{"code":"-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"List does not exist.\u000a\u000aThe page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."},"innererror":{"message":"List does not exist.\u000a\u000aThe page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","stacktrace":" at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(Guid webId, String strListName)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.ItemByInternalName(String strInternalName, Boolean bThrowException)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetList(Guid uniqueId, Boolean fetchMetadata)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetById(Guid uniqueId)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethod(Boolean mainRequestPath, Object value, ServerStub serverProxy, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation methodInfo, Boolean isExtensionMethod, Boolean isIndexerMethod)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathMember(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, Object value, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation& methodInfo)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)","internalexception":{"message":"List does not exist.\u000a\u000aThe page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.0x81020026","type":"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException","stacktrace":" at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)"}}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["1"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["82"],"SPRequestGuid":["29235e5e-b907-f47c-b422-c13bd7e6d2ae"],"request-id":["29235e5e-b907-f47c-b422-c13bd7e6d2ae"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4517"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Mon, 11 Aug 2014 07:08:01 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: Thanks for reply, its not migration. I try many things like app permissions, Database permission, host entry,re entry Register-SPWorkflowService, cummulative updats but nothing work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve Lookup Fields (Except Id field) directly in sharepoint 2013 workflow.

Suppose you have 2 list: Products list & Orders list

In Orders list you have a lookup field from Products list.

In workflow you can retrieve ProductId field from order list. And then use REST API call to get other product fields ( like title )

Comment: i'm able to retrive title field of lookupcolumn in developmet server and wvery thing working perfect in that system. i get error when i run workflow in production /_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000‌​')/Items(13)?%24select=ID%2CAgendaId%2CAgenda%2FTitle&%24expand=Agenda , In this REST call guid of list 0000000000, i think this is the only problem